# Quais as dependências no Maven para usar o JQWicket para integrar Wicket e Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, maven, wicket

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto Wicket-Hibernate-Spring. Até realizar a comunicação e persistência de objetos no banco, estava funcionando normalmente.

Após algum tempo, com aumento de alguns escopos, preciso utilizar JQWicket, que seria uma dependência para integrar Wicket e Jquery.

Estou me deparando com esse erro quando inicializo o servidor (Tomcat 7.0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/apache/wicket/request/resource/UrlResourceReference
at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.Bootstrap.install(Bootstrap.java:78)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.Bootstrap.install(Bootstrap.java:110)
at com.projeto.core.WicketApplication.init(WicketApplication.java:45)
at org.apache.wicket.Application.initApplication(Application.java:807)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:346)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:286)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.request.resource.UrlResourceReference
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 18 more
```

Acredito que o meu erro esteja em minhas dependências do Maven, mas não vejo o por que de estarem de alguma maneira erradas:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-util</artifactId>
                <classifier>tests</classifier>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-request</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.agilecoders.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-bootstrap-extensions</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-util</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>0.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.jqwicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>jqwicket</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Alguém já passou por algo parecido e possa compartilhar a experiencia?

**EDIÇÃO**

Parece que descobri a causa, mas não consigo desfazer o erro.
O JQWicket tenta utilizar a classe UrlResourceReference enquanto ela não faz parte do Wicket 1.5.3, mas sim do 6.19, que seria uma versão estavel acima. O por que, eu gostaria de entender, já que a versão do JQWicket parece ser a estável para o 1.5.3.

**EDIÇÃO 2**

Se eu mudar para a versão 6.19 do Wicket, o JQWicket acusa que há um método faltante na classe Url.  Um método que a classe Url do 1.5.3 tem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo *stack trace* seu problema está relacionado diretamente com a dependência [`wicket-bootstrap-extensions`](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap) e não com [`jqwicket`](https://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/).

[`jqwicket`](https://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/) realmente depende da versão `1.5.3` do `wicket`, como podemos ver nestes trechos do `pom.xml` dele:

```xml
<wicket.version>1.5.3</wicket.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
    <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Verificando a hierarquia de dependências, de acordo com as suas dependências, tudo leva a crer nisto. [`wicket-bootstrap-extensions`](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap) depende de versões mais recente do `wicket` (`6.x`), mas encontra a versão `1.5.3` em *runtime*.

Veja como está a hierarquia de dependência para [`wicket-bootstrap-extensions`](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap), antes das depedência de `wicket` serem omitidas pela exclusão que você faz:

[image: Wicket Boostrap Extensions]

Não encontrei uma versão de [`wicket-bootstrap-extensions`](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap) que dê suporte à versão `1.5.3` do `wicket`, já que a mais antiga, `0.8.0` depende da versão `6.6.0` do `wicket`.

Para solucionar isto você deverá:

- não usar [`wicket-bootstrap-extensions`](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap)
- **OU** encontrar uma alternativa ao [`jqwicket`](https://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/), como o [`wiquery`](https://github.com/WiQuery/wiquery), que utiliza versões mais recentes do `wicket`

Comment: Obrigado, Bruno. Vou verificar.